# Morrey's inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

From PDE Evans, 2nd edition, page 281:

> Now
>   \begin{align}
> \int_0^s \int_{\partial B(0,1)} |Du(x+tw)| \, dS(w) dt &=\int_0^s \int_{\partial B(x,t)} \frac{|Du(y)|}{t^{n-1}} \, dS(y) dt \\
> &= \int_{B(x,s)} \frac{|Du(y)|}{|x-y|^{n-1}} \, dy \\
> &\le \int_{B(x,r)} \frac{|Du(y)|}{|x-y|^{n-1}} \, dy,
> \end{align}
>   where we put $y=x+tw,t=|x-y|$.

Can I ask where does the $\frac 1{t^{n-1}}$ factor come from in the first inequality? Somehow this results from transforming the variables by letting $y=x+tw$.

---

Also, from page 282 of the textbook (part of the same proof of Morrey's inequality),

> Next, choose any two points $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and write $r :=|x-y|$. Let $W := B(x,r) \cap B(y,r)$. Then
>   $$|u(x)-u(y)| \le \frac 1{|W|} \left[ \int_W |u(x)-u(z)| \, dz + \int_W |u(y)-u(z)| \, dz \right]\tag{24}$$
>   But inequality $\text{(21)}$ allows us to estimate
>   \begin{align}
> \frac 1{|B(x,r)|} \int_W |u(x)-u(z)| \, dx &\le C \cdot \frac 1{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} |u(x)-u(z)| \, dz \\
> &\le C \left(\int_{B(x,r)} |Du|^p \, dz \right)^{\frac 1p} \left(\int_{B(x,r)} \frac{dz}{|x-z|^{(n-1)\frac{p}{p-1}}} \right)^{\frac{p-1}p} \\
> &\le C\left(r^{n-(n-1)\frac p{p-1}} \right)^{\frac{p-1}p} \|Du\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \\
> &= Cr^{1-\frac np} \|Du\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}.
> \end{align}

The only part I'm not understanding is how they were able to assert the following: $$\int_{B(x,r)} \frac{dz}{|x-z|^{(n-1)\frac{p}{p-1}}}=r^{n-(n-1)\frac p{p-1}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integration in polar coordinates (or spherical, in higher dimensions). Write $z=x+\rho\theta$ where $\theta\in S^{n-1}$ is a unit vector and $\rho\in [0,r]$. Then for any integrable $f$ we have 
$$
\int_{B(x,r)} f(z)\,dz = \int_0^r \int_{S^{n-1}} f(x+\rho \theta) \rho^{n-1}\,d\theta \,d\rho \tag{1}
$$
(Compare with $n=2$ case, when this is the usual polar coordinates.)

In your example the inner integral is easy because $f(x+\rho\theta) = \rho^{-(n-1)\frac{p}{p-1}}$. Integrating a constant over the unit sphere we pick up the factor of the surface area, which is a constant that depends only on $n$, traditionally denoted $\omega_{n-1}$.  Proceed to integrate:
$$
\int_0^r \omega_{n-1} \rho^{-(n-1)\frac{p}{p-1}} \rho^{n-1}\,d\rho
=\omega_{n-1} \rho^{n-(n-1)\frac{p}{p-1}}\bigg|_{\rho=0}^{\rho=r}
$$
which is the desired result.

---

Let me also bring this in line with "Calculus" Appendix  in the book. Evans does not turn to unit sphere in (1), but rather presents the formula as
$$
\int_{B(x,r)} f(z)\,dz = \int_0^r \int_{\rho S^{n-1}} f(x+\theta) \,d\theta \,d\rho 
$$
(his notation is different). This is the same as (1), because scaling an $(n-1)$-dimensional surface by factor of $\rho$ carries with it the Jacobian of $\rho^{n-1}$.